# Deploying extra files using MSBuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, msbuild, teamcity

We're using Teamcity, Git, and MSBuild to deploy our website.

Our website runs the Sitecore CMS. It needs to be in the root directory, not a virtual directory.

I don't want to include all hundreds of Sitecore related files into our code repository, as they never change. I am able to xcopy them in after the site is deployed, but that adds a minute to each build and seems inefficient.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MSBuild to copy your files "incrementally". It is called [batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). MSBuild compare datetime stamp of input files with datetime stamp of outputs and if some of inputs datetime > output datetime then target or task will be executed.

Comment: The only problem with checking datetime stamps is that if the source is pulled down to a machine that has never had the deployment run before (i.e automation build server). The time stamps might not indicate that files have changed since all the timestamps will be set to the current date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [Incremental Builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It checks for previously built components that are still up-to-date and therefore do not need to be rebuild or synced with the deployment server. It only re-builds files that have changed. However, if your build machine changes or your builds are cleaned before compiling then the time stamps could cause you problems.

If your files have not changed in content, but when you pull the code down from source control and the time-stamp of the files are set to the to the current time of the build machine when the build begins then you could look at applying a SHA hash code to your deployed files and your build files.

Since the SHA hash code does not look at time stamps it will allow you to copy only the files that have file content changes.